# List of dicts: sort by dict's value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of dicts like below:

```
[
 {'init_time': datetime.time(14, 0), 'end_time': datetime.time(19, 0), 'value': 5.2}, 
 {'init_time': datetime.time(17, 0), 'end_time': datetime.time(18, 0), 'value': 6.5},
 {'init_time': datetime.time(15, 0), 'end_time': datetime.time(17, 0), 'value': 2.5}
]
```

How can I sort this list by the value of each dict's `init_time`? Usually with `sorted` one is able to sort a dict based on either key or value, but in my case, I'm not interested in sorting the dict but the list, using the dict's values.

For example, the output of the above would be:

```
[
 {'init_time': datetime.time(14, 0), 'end_time': datetime.time(19, 0), 'value': 5.2}, 
 {'init_time': datetime.time(15, 0), 'end_time': datetime.time(17, 0), 'value': 2.5}
 {'init_time': datetime.time(17, 0), 'end_time': datetime.time(18, 0), 'value': 6.5},
]
```

Comment: You can sort a list of dicts by a specific key value, take a look at [Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python's `sorted` function has a `key` parameter that will be used in comparisons,

```
new_list = sorted(old_list, key=lambda item: item["init_time"])
```

Comment: oh, I always understood that `key` parameter as an element of the main object I'm sorting, in this case the list. Didn't know I could use it this way with `lambda`